# C++ Asynchronous Agents Strange Behavior

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I started with the basic-agents.cpp here [Asynchronous Agents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492627(v=vs.120).aspx) but I wanted to test out a loop so I did

```
class agent1 : public agent
{
public:
    explicit agent1(ISource<int>& source, ITarget<string>& target)
        : _source(source)
        , _target(target)
    {
    }

protected:
void run()
{
    std::cout << "type: ";
    std::string a;
    std::getline(std::cin, a);

    // send the request
    std::cout << "agent1: sending request... " << endl;

    send(_target, a);

    // Read the response
    int response = receive(_source);

    std::cout << "agent1: received '" << response << "'." << endl;

    // move the agent to the finished state.
    done();
    }

private:
    ISource<int>& _source;
    ITarget<string >& _target;
};
```

and for agent2

```
class agent2 : public agent
{
public:
    explicit agent2(ISource<string>& source, ITarget<int>& target)
        : _source(source)
        , _target(target)
    {
    }

protected:
void run()
{
    // read the request
    string request = receive(_source);

    std::cout << "agent2: received '" << request << "'." << std::endl;

    // send the response
    std::cout << "agent2: sending response..." << std::endl;

    code += 1;
    send(_target, code);

    // move the agent to the finished state
    done();

public:
    int code;
private:
    ISource<string>& _source;
    ITarget<int>& _target;
};
```

and the main running the agents as

```
    int oldcode = 0;
    while (oldcode < 10)
    {
        agent1 first_agent(buffer2, buffer1);
        agent2 second_agent(buffer1, buffer2);
        second_agent.code = oldcode;

        // Step 3: start the agents.  The runtime calls the run method on each agent.
        first_agent.start();
        second_agent.start();

        // Step 4: wait for both agents to finish
        agent::wait(&first_agent);
        agent::wait(&second_agent);
        oldcode = second_agent.code;
        std::cout << "In Step 2 loop, oldcode: " << oldcode << std::endl;
    }
```

The funny thing I get is this output

```
type: a
agent1: sending request...
agent2: received 'a'.
agent2: sending response...
agent1: received '1'.
In Step 2 loop, oldcode: 1
type: b
agent1: sending request...
agent1: received '1'.
agent2: received 'b'.
agent2: sending response...
In Step 2 loop, oldcode: 2
type: c
agent1: sending request...
agent1: received '2'.
agent2: receivede 'c'.
agent2: sending response...
In Step 2 loop, oldcode: 3
```

Note that agent 1 reported receiving '1' twice at the start with an out of sequence receive in the response to 'b'.  This does not happen anywhere else and is consistent.

Is there anything wrong with my looping asynchronous agents in this way?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728068(v=vs.120).aspx
"Unlike with an unbounded_buffer object, the receive function does not remove the message from the overwrite_buffer object. If the consumer reads from the message buffer more than one time before the producer overwrites that message, the receiver obtains the same message every time."